# ruby encoding error on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, cucumber

Wondering if anyone has ever come across the error

```
 Caught Encoding::CompatibilityError at '{"command_id":"cc8bf': incompatible encoding regexp match (ASCII-8BIT regexp with UTF-8 string) (JSON::ParserError)
```

I get this the following is called

```
expect(page.element.text.to_s.force_encoding("UTF-8").match msg).to be_true
```

As you can see, I have added "to_s.force_encoding("UTF-8")" but i still get the error.

My version of ruby is 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

Running on a mac and the tests pass with no errors.

Comment: The error here is because `msg` is an ascii-8bit regex. How are you assigning the `msg` variable?

Comment: msg = 'Profile updated'